# What to do if same parent data is shared by child data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have 2 tables

```
1. Branches
2. Departments
```

**Branches**

```
BranchID    BranchName
1            BranchA
2.           BranchB
```

**Departments**

```
DepartmentID     DepartmentName fk_BranchID
1                    IT           1
2.                   IT           2
3.                   ENG          2
```

Now as you can see, every Branch has departments but some departments are shared among the Branches. I mean same departments but under 2 Branches.

Now this is what I have done above, my table structure.

But when I use it in somewhere. It will shot 2 IT in drop down or collection of website etc. Shall I put different names like IT (BranchA), IT (BranchB)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want three tables:

- `Branches`
- `Departments`
- `BranchDepartments`

These would look like:

Branches:

```
BranchID    BranchName
1            BranchA
2            BranchB
```

Departments:

```
DepartmentID     DepartmentName
    1                 IT
    2                 ENG
```

BranchDepartments:

```
BranchDepartmentID     BranchID     DepartmentId
    1                   1             1
    2                   2             1
    3                   2             2
```

This is usually how you represent a many-to-many relationship in SQL.